How to show Loading when the key changes in useSWR even if the data for the key already exist in cache?
I am using useSWR hook for data fetching. I want to show Loading, whenever the key changes. I have included the filter state in the key of useSWR, so whenever the state updates, it will call the API.
For e.g., on the UI, when I click on a Completed checkbox (Please refer the link of the playground), for the first time the value of isLoading is true. Then if I uncheck and check the Completed checkbox again, the value of isLoading is false, because the data already exist in the cache for the same key.
I know that the useSWR hook is also exposing isValidating. I can't use this because I am also polling the api every 5 seconds. So, if I use isValidating then on the UI, loading is displayed every 5 seconds.
I want to show Loading whenever the user applies any filter. Any help would be appreciated
const [filter, setFilter] = useState({
   filterText: '',
   showCompleted: false,
});

const { data, error, isLoading, mutate } = useSWR(
    ['https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', filter],
    async ([url, filter]) => {
        const res = await fetch(`${url}?completed=${filter.showCompleted}`);
        return await res.json();
    }
);

Playground - https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-n8hjaa?file=src%2FApp.jsx
